# SSMS 18.9.2 Crashing shortly after loading

Tags: windows-10, crash, ssms

I'm running SSMS 18.9.2 on a Windows 10 computer.

SSMS crashes as soon as I start typing in an SQL template, as soon as an auto-complete list pops up.

I get the following from Windows Event Viewer

```
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   at LiteDB.StreamExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<TryLock>b__0()
   at LiteDB.FileHelper.TryExec(System.Action, System.TimeSpan)
   at LiteDB.StreamExtensions.TryLock(System.IO.FileStream, Int64, Int64, System.TimeSpan)
   at LiteDB.FileDiskService.Lock(LiteDB.LockState, System.TimeSpan)
   at LiteDB.LockService.Write()
   at LiteDB.LiteEngine.Transaction[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String, Boolean, System.Func`2<LiteDB.CollectionPage,Int32>)
   at LiteDB.LiteEngine.Insert(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<LiteDB.BsonDocument>, LiteDB.BsonType)
   at LiteDB.LiteEngine.Insert(System.String, LiteDB.BsonDocument, LiteDB.BsonType)
   at LiteDB.LiteFileStream.WriteChunks()
   at LiteDB.LiteFileStream.Flush()
   at LiteDB.LiteFileStream.Dispose(Boolean)
```

And the following too

```
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2019.150.18386.0, time stamp: 0x60e54ecb
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x03f493ae
Faulting process ID: 0x61d8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7959a3013810d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: 80e0774c-ab69-472e-b26a-1ec055d65650
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
   at LiteDB.LiteFileStream.Finalize()
```

I have tried re-installing SSMS several times with no change in behaviour. I've also tried a .NET repair tool for MS but this didn't solve my problem.

I have search StackExchange and other sites for a solution to this. I have come across what seem to be similar issues but haven't come across one referring to **LiteDB.StreamExtensions**

```
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
   **at LiteDB.StreamExtensions**
```

I'm now unable to use SSMS as it constantly crashes as soon as I start typing a statement.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you install a lower/previous version? To check if it will also crash or not. Can you repair/reinstall/remove Litedb, and check if the error persists?

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both the current and older version, the problem still persists.

I have read the documentation about LiteDB and  (embarrassingly) can't figure out how to reinstall it in the context of SSMS. Any guidance on this would be appreciated.